# Javascript objects: get parent

Tags: javascript

I have the following (nested) object:

```
obj: { subObj: { foo: 'hello world' } };
```

Next thing I do is to reference the subobject like this:

```
var s = obj.subObj;
```

Now what I would like to do is to get a reference to the object `obj` out of the variable `s`.
Something like:

```
var o = s.parent;
```

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: JavaScript is quite well documented, see e.g. the [ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) or read a book like *JavaScript. The Definitive Guide* by David Flanagan. BTW, there is no such thing as a JSON object: JSON is just a notation of JavaScript objects.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Sorry for the JSON, I was just putting this one in because I was working on a JSON related snippet - and I think it could be most useful there (JSON) to get the parent object.

Comment: `obj.subObj` is just a reference of the Object. If it were possible to get the "parent" of the Object, it would be a mess, simply because there can be multiple pointers pointing to the same Object and it will return multiple parents.

Comment: @JLRishe - I just ran across something today and wanted to run it by you.  My original [now deleted] comment claimed that *strings are instances of the string constructor*, to which you called my error.  However, `var my_string = "asdf"; my_string instanceof String; /* false */ my_string.constructor === String /* true */`.  Can you explain?

Comment: @RyanWheale When you access a property on a primitive value, it is [autoboxed into a wrapper object](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/the-secret-life-of-javascript-primitives/), so what you are seeing is the `constructor` property on a `String` object. You will see a similar outcome if you try `(0).constructor === Number` or `true.constructor === Boolean`.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel "BTW, there is no such thing as a JSON object: JSON is just a notation of JavaScript objects." - maybe not in theory, but in practice JSON object is an JS object that is serializable back to JSON. I think it is reasonable to refer to such objects as "JSON objects".

Comment: @AdrianKalbarczyk *I think it is reasonable to refer to such objects as "JSON objects"* No, actually, it's wrong, and confusing.

Comment: @torazaburo why? MDN uses it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON, Android Java has JSONobject class etc.

Comment: Java's usage of the term JSON object means something completely different. It refers to a Java type which is used to hold objects to be serialized to or from JSON. As for the MDN article, it unfortunately perpetuates confusing and incorrect ideas about JSON--remember MDN is written my mere mortals like you and me. All you really need to know about JSON can be found on json.org, where it states,  **JSON is a text format**.

Comment: It means exactly the same thing I am talking about from the beginning. One thing is JSON as a text format, the other thing is JSON object - a result of parsing JSON in a programming language.

Comment: This answer here helped me to solve the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-and-arays-by-string-path

Comment: Basically, you have to create a reference to the parent

Answer (score 79, accepted):

No.  There is no way of knowing which object it came from.

`s` and `obj.subObj` both simply have references to the same object.

You could also do:

```
var obj = { subObj: {foo: 'hello world'} };
var obj2 = {};
obj2.subObj = obj.subObj;
var s = obj.subObj;
```

You now have three references, `obj.subObj`, `obj2.subObj`, and `s`, to the same object.  None of them is special.

Answer (score 149):

A nested object (child) inside another object (parent) cannot get data directly from its parent.

Have a look on this:

```
var main = {
    name : "main object",
    child : {
        name : "child object"
    }
};
```

If you ask the main object what its child name is (`main.child.name`) you will get it.
Instead you cannot do it vice versa because the child doesn't know who its parent is.
(You can get `main.name` but you won't get `main.child.parent.name`).

By the way, a function could be useful to solve this clue.
Let's extend the code above:

```
var main = {
    name : "main object",
    child : {
        name : "child object"
    },
    init : function() {
        this.child.parent = this;
        delete this.init;
        return this;
    }
}.init();
```

Inside the `init` function you can get the parent object simply calling `this`.
So we define the `parent` property directly inside the `child` object.
Then (optionally) we can remove the `init` method.
Finally we give the main object back as output from the `init` function.

If you try to get `main.child.parent.name` now you will get it right.
It is a little bit tricky but it works fine.

Comment: Does this create any performance issues when working with large parents or is it just creating a second reference to a single object?

Comment: @Josiah: Not much performance issue. It is just creating a second reference to the parent object.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This is smart, exactly what I needed.

Comment: It will go infinitely down when deepCloning and break the app. main.child.parent.child.parent.child.parent.child.parent.child.parent...

Comment: I want to add that it will not work if you call `new (main.init)()` because `this instanceof main.init`

Answer (score 50):

This is an old question but as I came across it looking for an answer I thought I will add my answer to this to help others as soon as they got the same problem.

I have a structure like this:

```
var structure = {
    "root":{
        "name":"Main Level",
        nodes:{
            "node1":{
                "name":"Node 1"  
            },
            "node2":{
                "name":"Node 2"  
            },
            "node3":{
                "name":"Node 3"  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Currently, by referencing one of the sub nodes I don't know how to get the parent node with it's name value "Main Level".

Now I introduce a recursive function that travels the structure and adds a parent attribute to each node object and fills it with its parent like so.

```
var setParent = function(o){
     if(o.nodes != undefined){
          for(n in o.nodes){
              o.nodes[n].parent = o;
              setParent(o.nodes[n]);
          }
     }
}
```

Then I just call that function and can now get the parent of the current node in this object tree.

```
setParent(structure.root);
```

If I now have a reference to the seconds sub node of root, I can just call.

```
var node2 = structure.root.nodes["node2"];
console.log(node2.parent.name);
```

and it will output "Main Level".

Hope this helps..

Comment: This helps me greatly!  Even though JavaScript doesn't natively provide a "parent" property we can add one manually if needed.

Comment: @Nonlinearsound what about performance when the objects are large with many levels of nesting?

Comment: Yes I did the same. Strange that JS doesn't have this built in.

Comment: @MSC Not strange. That would be ridiculous overhead for large objects where this is not used or wanted, just like Sajid is asking about.

Comment: I like this one better because I don't need to write something for all children :-)

Answer (score 31):

Many of the answers here involve looping through an object and "manually" (albeit programmatically) creating a parent property that stores the reference to the parent. The two ways of implementing this seem to be...

1. Use an `init` function to loop through at the time the nested object is created, or...
2. Supply the nested object to a function that fills out the parent property

Both approaches have the same issue...

**How do you maintain parents as the nested object grows/changes??**

If I add a new sub-sub-object, how does it get its parent property filled? If you're (1) using an `init` function, the initialization is already done and over, so you'd have to (2) pass the object through a function to search for new children and add the appropriate parent property.

**Using ES6 Proxy to add `parent` whenever an object/sub-object is `set`**

The approach below is to create a handler for a proxy always adds a parent property each time an object is set. I've called this handler the `parenter` handler. The `parenter` responsibilities are to recognize when an object is being set and then to...

1. Create a dummy proxy with the appropriate `parent` and the `parenter` handler

   ```
   var p = new Proxy({parent: target}, parenter);
   ```
2. Copy in the supplied objects properties-- **Because you're setting the proxy properties in this loop the `parenter` handler is working recursively; nested objects are given parents at each level**

   ```
   for(key in value){
       p[key] = value[key];
     }
   ```
3. Set the proxy not the supplied object

   ```
   return target[prop] = p;
   ```

**Full code**

```
var parenter = {
  set: function(target, prop, value){
    if(typeof value === "object"){
      var p = new Proxy({parent: target}, parenter);
      for(key in value){
        p[key] = value[key];
      }
      return target[prop] = p;
    }else{
      target[prop] = value;
    }
  }
}

var root = new Proxy({}, parenter);

// some examples
root.child1 = {
    color: "red", 
    value: 10, 
    otherObj: { 
       otherColor: "blue", 
       otherValue: 20
    }
}

// parents exist/behave as expected
console.log(root.child1.color)                 // "red"
console.log(root.child1.otherObj.parent.color) // "red"

// new children automatically have correct parent
root.child2 = {color: "green", value3: 50};
console.log(root.child2.parent.child1.color)   // "red"

// changes are detected throughout
root.child1.color = "yellow"
console.log(root.child2.parent.child1.color)   // "yellow"
```

Notice that all root children always have parent properties, even children that are added later.

Comment: Great! In my case I have a problem with this code because my project use "use strict". To fix it I just add "return true" at the end of "set" function

Answer (score 8):

There is a more 'smooth' solution for this :)

```
var Foo = function(){
  this.par = 3;

  this.sub = new(function(t){ //using virtual function to create sub object and pass parent object via 't'
    this.p = t;
    this.subFunction = function(){
      alert(this.p.par);
    }
  })(this);
}

var myObj = new Foo();
myObj.sub.subFunction() // will popup 3;

myObj.par = 5;
myObj.sub.subFunction() // will popup 5;
```

Answer (score 6):

To further iterate on Mik's answer, you could also recursivey attach a parent to all nested objects.

```
var myApp = {

    init: function() {
        for (var i in this) {
            if (typeof this[i] == 'object') {
                    this[i].init = this.init;
                    this[i].init();
                    this[i].parent = this;
            }
        }
        return this;
    },

    obj1: {
        obj2: {
            notify: function() {
                console.log(this.parent.parent.obj3.msg);
            }
        }
    },

    obj3: {
        msg: 'Hello'
    }

}.init();

myApp.obj1.obj2.notify();
```

http://jsbin.com/zupepelaciya/1/watch?js,console

Answer (score 4):

You could try this(this uses a constructor, but I'm sure you can change it around a bit):

```
function Obj() {
    this.subObj = {
        // code
    }
    this.subObj.parent = this;
}
```

Comment: I used your example but I simply created a reference variable in the parent and just pass it to the sub objects that need it when needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I have been working on a solution to finding the parent object of the current object for my own pet project. Adding a reference to the parent object within the current object creates a cyclic relationship between the two objects.

Consider -

```
var obj = {
    innerObj: {},
    setParent: function(){
        this.innerObj.parent = this;
    }
};
obj.setParent();
```

The variable obj will now look like this -

obj.innerObj.parent.innerObj.parent.innerObj...

This is not good. The only solution that I have found so far is to create a function which iterates over all the properties of the outermost Object until a match is found for the current Object and then that Object is returned.

Example -

```
var obj = {
    innerObj: {
        innerInnerObj: {}
    }
};

var o = obj.innerObj.innerInnerObj,
    found = false;

var getParent = function (currObj, parObj) {
    for(var x in parObj){
        if(parObj.hasOwnProperty(x)){
            if(parObj[x] === currObj){
                found = parObj;
            }else if(typeof parObj[x] === 'object'){
                getParent(currObj, parObj[x]);
            }
        }
    }
    return found;
};

var res = getParent(o, obj); // res = obj.innerObj
```

Of course, without knowing or having a reference to the outermost object, there is no way to do this. This is not a practical nor is it an efficient solution. I am going to continue to work on this and hopefully find a good answer for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try this until a non-no answer appears:

```
function parent() {
  this.child;
  interestingProperty = "5";
  ...
}

function child() {
  this.parent;
  ...
}

a = new parent();
a.child = new child();
a.child.parent = a; // this gives the child a reference to its parent

alert(a.interestingProperty+" === "+a.child.parent.interestingProperty);
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need the child to store the parents this variable. As the Parent is the only object that has access to it's this variable it will also need a function that places the this variable into the child's that variable, something like this.

```
var Parent = {
  Child : {
    that : {},
  },
  init : function(){
    this.Child.that = this;
  }
}
```

To test this out try to run this in Firefox's Scratchpad, it worked for me.

```
var Parent = {
  data : "Parent Data",

  Child : {
    that : {},
    data : "Child Data",
    display : function(){
      console.log(this.data);
      console.log(this.that.data);
    }
  },
  init : function(){
    this.Child.that = this;
  }
}

Parent.init();
Parent.Child.display();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in keeping the parent value in child attribute

```
var Foo = function(){
    this.val= 4;
    this.test={};
    this.test.val=6;
    this.test.par=this;
}

var myObj = new Foo();
alert(myObj.val);
alert(myObj.test.val);
alert(myObj.test.par.val);
```

Answer (score 0):

when I load in a json object I usually setup the relationships by iterating through the object arrays like this:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < some.json.objectarray.length; i++) {
        var p = some.json.objectarray[i];
        for (var j = 0; j < p.somechildarray.length; j++) {
            p.somechildarray[j].parent = p;
        }
    }
```

then you can access the parent object of some object in the somechildarray by using .parent