# How to get data from a JavaScript Object Literal

Tags: javascript

I want to find a way to get the name "objName" from the function "fn" defined inside the "objName".

See the comments to see how it should work.

```
this.objName = {
    fn : function () {console.log("????");}
}

this.objName.fn() // objName
```

Obviously, the "fn" function will not called in this way, but from a JavaScript Button action event. (the button is defined inside this.objName = { .... } )

Comment: You can't without writing smelly code. What's the bigger problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript objects: get parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980763/javascript-objects-get-parent)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ugly but what about

```
this.ns = {};
this.ns.objName = {
    fn : function () {
        for (var k in ns)
            if (this === ns[k]) {
              alert(k);  
              return;
             }
     }
}

this.ns.objName.fn(); // objName
```

You could drop `ns` and use window.

**Edit**; after your update, if you want to access the object from within an event handler created by that object;

```
var Obj = new function() {
   this.objName = {
      id: 42,
      makeLink: function () {
         var self = this;
         document.getElementById("someelement").onclick = function(e) {
            alert(self.id); // 42
         };
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this before... until I realized (after looking here at stackoverflow) that if you are able to write:

```
this.objName.fn()
```

you already know what 'objName' is.