# Reflection in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reflection

I have been looking into the possibility of reflection in JavaScript. I already have a simple reflector which can list the members of an object/function, like so:

```
window["Foo"] = {
    "Bar": {
        "Test": function () {
            this.x = 32;
            this._hello = "Hello World";
            this._item = 123.345;

            this.hello = function() {
                alert("hello");
            };

            this.goodbye = function() {
                alert("goodbye");
            }
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var x = new Foo.Bar.Test();
    Reflect(new Foo.Bar.Test());
});

function Reflect(obj) {
    for (var item in obj) {
        $("body").append(item + "(" + typeof obj[item] + ") = " + obj[item] + "<br />");
    }
}
```

**Results:**

> x(number) = 32
>
> _hello(string) = Hello World
>
> _item(number) = 123.345
>
> hello(function) = function () { alert("hello"); }
>
> goodbye(function) = function () { alert("goodbye"); }

The next part of my challenge is to build something which can reflect back (if possible) an objects name, and the path to the object.

using this example:...

```
var x = new Foo.Bar.Test();
```

How can I reflect back "Test", from x? For example:

```
ReflectName(x); //returns "Test";
```

Also how can I reflect back the path to x? For example:

```
ReflectPath(x) //returns Foo.Bar.Test
```

Is is possible to do these two things using JavaScript? I have researched this, and so far have not managed to come up with any viable solutions.

I do not want a solution that requires hard coding the name and path of the object/function, as this would defeat the point of using reflection.

Comment: not possible. You could find `x` in `Foo` but that doesn't ensure that's where it came from.

Comment: `window.Foo = window.Bar = …` - which "name" would you want now?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are no classes in JavaScript (although due to code style which for reasons unknown to me imitates Java you could think there are some).  `Foo.Bar.Test` does not mean class `Test` registered in namespace `Foo.Bar`, but function which is assigned as attribute `Test` of some object which is assigned as attribute `Bar` of some object known as `Foo`.

You can't do reflection like "give me all variables to which number `7` is assigned", consequently you can't list all the objects which hold `Test` in one of their attributes.

This is actually good and opens new possibilities, but might be confusing in the beginning.

BTW Since there are no classes in JavaScript, I believe term *reflection* is not very fortunate.  And `new Foo()` does not mean "create new instance of Foo", but "create a new object and execute function `Foo` in context of that object, and finally return it.  Yeah, the `new` keyword is very confusing, if you want to do anything more advanced in JavaScript, never trust your Java/C# experience.  JavaScript fakes Java (I suppose to not scare newcomers and allow them to do easy things quickly), but it's very different.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I understand the points made. Like you said, JavaScript does not have classes or namespaces. I am actually looking at it from the TypeScript perspective, which has classes and modules. Understandably this has no real significance as it compiles to JavaScript anyway, and therefore can only comply with how JavaScript formulates Objects/Functions. I am beginning to think that the only way I will achieve what I am trying to achieve, will be to have a Type dictionary, where each type may have a unique identifier pointing to its type information in the dictionary.

Comment: @series0ne: I'm not familiar with TypeScript, but since it registers types, it may add reflection to JavaScript too.

Comment: unfortunately this is not the case. TypeScript is just a superset of JavaScript, and compiles to JavaScript, therefore what I am trying to achieve is no more achievable from TypeScript than it is from JavaScript. The only things TypeScript brings to the table are syntactic sugar, so for example, if I write a class in TypeScript, and then inherit that class elsewhere, "class Foo extends Bar" becomes the "prototypal inheritance" equivalent of the statement.

Comment: this answer works and gives the type name!: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47447046/1915920

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible in JavaScript. (To get a deeper understanding of JavaScript's type system, I recommend reading [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20150211073056/http://vijayan.ca:80/blog/2012/02/21/javascript-type-model/).)

The best approximation you can do is [querying over a *static* JSON structure](http://jsonselect.org/#docs).

Comment: Nice idea! Inspecting `window` object properties which start with capital letter (there are not so many of them), then their properties etc. should give pretty nice results.  The only thing to remember is that objects have prototypes and their properties should (?) be omitted.

Comment: The first link no longer exists.   :(

Answer (score 2):

Answer to your first question

```
function ReflectName(obj) { return obj.__proto__.constructor.name }
```

Second question is a bit more difficult and would require more setup with the definitions.

It is answered a bit better here: [Javascript objects: get parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980763/javascript-objects-get-parent)