# How to get the reference of parent/wrapping object?

Tags: javascript

I have the following object.

```
ou.map : {
   settings : {
   },

   basePath : './path/';
   marker_setting : {
     img   :  this.basePath + 'image.png';
   },

   fun : function() {
      alert ( this.maker_setting.img  );
      //alert ( this.basePath + this.maker_setting.img ); Right now, I am using this where this.maker_setting.img is simply 'image.png'
   }

}
```

Here, value of `ou.map.marker_setting.img` comes out to be `undefinedimage.png` , but I want that to be `./path/image.png` . How can I do that?

**Edit**
I am open to change the complete approach as well. All I want is, one namespace having marker_setting and basePath and one main method which can use property in marker_setting.

Also, I tried all these

```
img   :  this.basePath + 'image.png';
img   :  basePath + 'image.png';
img   :  ou.map.basePath + 'image.png';
```

None, of these gave desired output. Let me know if any other info is required.

Comment: here `this` refers to the context where the statement gets executed.

Comment: have a look at [Javascript objects: get parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980763/javascript-objects-get-parent)

Comment: this answer uses an init function to initialise a parent http://stackoverflow.com/a/10170826/2022859

Answer (score 0):

The value of `this` depends on how and where your above code gets executed, i.e. the context where `ou.map` object gets defined in your case.

For example:

```
function foo() {
   ou.map = {
      // here this would be 'x'
   }
}

foo.call('x'); // means the value of "this" inside foo() will be 'x'
```

Comment: this wouldn't work, how would you reference self in this case?

Comment: Edited the answer to remove the `self` part. The rest of the info might be useful to others.