# how to access parent of javascript object

Tags: javascript, class, oop, object

I have a slideshow class looking like this:

```
//Our slideshow class
function Slideshow(moduleId) {

  this.moduleId = moduleId;

  this.activeSlide = null;

  this.slides = new Array();

  this.newRound();

}
```

and I instantiate it telling it what module it is on like this

```
self.modules[moduleId].slideshow = new Slideshow(moduleId);
```

Now as you can see, it is already "mounted" on a module named by the moduleId, so my question is: Is this object (the instance of Slideshow) aware of it's parent?

Can I find out the moduleId by doing something like

```
parent.name
```

and get the moduleId that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Because JavaScript passes objects by reference, the same `Slideshow` object could actually be referenced by several "parent" objects simultaneously.

Comment: ok, so the only way really for slideshow to know what "node" or "moduleId" in my case it os "mounted" on is to do what I did?

Comment: Right. If you want to maintain a reference to another object within the Slideshow object, you can pass a reference to that object (whether it's a "parent" or not) in the constructor.

Comment: From a similar question on StackOverflow: "A nested object (child) inside another object (parent) cannot get data directly from its parent." (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980763/javascript-objects-get-parent).

One option is to pass the Slideshow object as a parameter to the modules's constructor, which could set up a 'parent' property on the Slideshow.

Comment: Super, that totally solves my problem, I'll pass a reference to the parent in the constructor. Many thanks! I guess I will still need the moduleId passed like I have it in the constructor as well, but this is great news anyways.