# Access the parents name of a JSON object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON object that has a nested structure like this: http://pastebin.com/tNXNDVQe . 
I am trying to find all the elements that have a common parent, in the below example the parent is PRI. It is not clear to me why I can not get the parent name like this: `pdData.parent.name` ?

I am recursively checking each and every object like this:

```
var pdName = ["Damage Ratio"];
var pdParent = ["PRI"];
var pdData = // the JSON object


        function findTreeBranchInfo(pdData, pdName, pdParent) {
            if (pdParent.some(function(currentValue) {
                console.log(pdData);
                return (pdData.parent.name == currentValue); //does not work

            })) {
                console.log("match");
                pdTempIds.push(pdData.id);
                createSpinner(pdData.id, pdData.weight, pdData.name);
            }

            (pdData.children || []).forEach(function(currentItem) {
                findTreeBranchInfo(currentItem, [pdName], [pdParent]);
            });
        }
```

In the above loop, `console.log(pdData);` returns:

```
Object {name: "Damage Ratio", weight: 33, level: 3.1, depth: 2, parent: Object…}
    .   depth: 2
    .   id: 40
    .   level: 3.1
    .   name: "Damage Ratio"
    .   parent: Object
      .   children: Array[3]
      .   depth: 1
      .   id: 41
      .   level: 2
      .   name: "PRI"
      .   parent: Object
      .   weight: 50
      .   x: 40
      .   x0: 40
      .   y: 180
      .   y0: 180
      .   __proto__: Object
```

Comment: Could you create a fiddle? I'd like to inspect that Object

Comment: Already answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980763/javascript-objects-get-parent.
I am sorry to say you will be disappointed.

Comment: *I am trying to find all the elements that have a common parent* you want to get all the childrens of a given object, right ?

Comment: Nathan P, yes that is correct

Comment: inside a D3.js function I am able to access the parents name like this:

`nodeEnter.append("text")
  .on("click", function(d) {
   pdName = d.name;
   pdData = data;
   pdWeight = d.weight;
   pdParent = d.parent.name;
   $('#projectDefWeightDialog').empty();
   findTreeBranchInfo(pdData, [pdName], [pdParent]);
   updateButton();
});`