# Javascript: get parent object key name from within child

Tags: javascript

I have the following object:

```
var process = {
    template1: {
        ref: // here I want to get 'template1'
    }
}
```

How can I access the parent key name as above?

Comment: If I understand you'd have to declare the object first, then do `process.template1.ref = process.template1`

Comment: Please provide more information. Do you want to create a self reference?

Comment: `ref: function() { alert('my parent is ' + this); }`

Comment: question: why? What problem are you trying to address that requires the template1 ref knows its owner?

Comment: Thanks to those linking to duplicate question which I missed. Long story, Mike, but I have a structure similar to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17923310/521392). As you can see, sometimes there is good reason to want to know the parent. Torazaburo, 'this' returns the entire object, not the name (string) which is what I wanted.