# Full object name

Tags: typescript

Hi there I am new in typescript and i'd like to ask if it is possible get full name of class include module names

I have module like this

```
module System {
  export module Collections {
    export class MyClass{
    }
  }
}
```

than in another module i will create instance of MyClass

```
var inst = new System.Collections.MyClass();
inst.AssemblyQualifiedName()
```

and result will be `System.Collections.MyClass`

I need this for unique identifying instance/types in collection and for creating instance from string ...

Something like `AssemblyQualifiedName` in c#

Comment: I am able get class name 

GetType(): Type {
            return new Type(this.constructor.toString().match(/function (\w*)/)[1]);
        }

like this but namespase ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible right out of the box. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2980763/188246) for more reference.

**Possible Solutions**

I'm not sure why you'd want or need to do this, but some possible solutions to your problem could be one of the following:

1. Add a static property (ex. `fullyQualifiedName`) that contains a string with the fully qualified name in it. Write a unit test to run through your modules to ensure the name is correct on any class that has that static property.
2. Add a static property again, but this time have your build script automatically fill in the name property.
3. Have a method that runs at the start of your application that will fill in the static property of any classes in the module passed to it.

**Example**

An example of how to do this is the following:

```
module TestModule {
    export class TestClass1 {
        // initialize it to undefined or null to ensure the
        // typescript compiler adds it as a property
        static fullyQualifiedName: string = undefined as any;
    }

    export module OtherModule {
        export class TestClass2 {
            static fullyQualifiedName: string = undefined as any;
        }

        export class TestClass3 {
        }
    }
}

function fillFullyQualifiedName(m: any, name: string) {
    // if it's a module
    if (typeof m === "object") {
        for (const propName of Object.keys(m)) {            
            fillFullyQualifiedName(m[propName], name + "." + propName);
        }
    }
    // else, if it's a class with the fullyQualifiedName property
    else if (typeof m === "function" && m.hasOwnProperty("fullyQualifiedName")) {
        m["fullyQualifiedName"] = name;
    }
}

fillFullyQualifiedName(TestModule, "TestModule");

// some tests...
TestModule.TestClass1.fullyQualifiedName === "TestModule.TestClass1";
TestModule.OtherModule.TestClass2.fullyQualifiedName === "TestModule.OtherModule.TestClass2";
TestModule.OtherModule.TestClass3["fullyQualifiedName"] == null;
```

I didn't test that very much, but it should help you get the idea and apply it to any of the possible solutions I listed above.

Comment: I think this only works for exported properties though.

Comment: @Thomas yeah, if the class or module isn't exported then it won't work.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the TypeScript compiler API (requires Node.js), e.g.:

```
import ts = require("typescript");    

class Sample
    {
        private program: ts.Program = null;

        constructor(sourceFiles: string[])
        {
            var options: ts.CompilerOptions = { noLib: true };
            var host = ts.createCompilerHost(options)
            this.program = ts.createProgram(sourceFiles, options, host)
            this.program.getSourceFiles().forEach(file => this.doSomethingWithTheFile(file));
        }

        ...

        private getQualifiedName(node: ts.Node): string 
        {
            var symbol = this.program.getTypeChecker().getSymbolAtLocation(node);
            if (!symbol)
                return null;
            return this.program.getTypeChecker().getFullyQualifiedName(symbol);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to do this. Classes in JavaScript are just values, and there's no mechanism to say "where did I get this value from?"