# Get this of this

Tags: javascript, object, methods, this

(purely fictional!)

How can `descend()` return 1,2,3...?

```
obj = {
    val: 1,
    obj: {
        val: 2,
        obj: {
            val: 3,
            obj: {
                val: 4,
                descend: function() {
                    return this.val;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

obj.obj.obj.obj.descend();
```

Comment: This just return 4 not 1,2,3,4

Comment: @BhojendraNepal I know. Hence the question.

Comment: It can’t unless it has some other means of reference, and `var x = obj.obj.obj.obj; x.descend();` will always have the same effect.

Comment: @minitech, so how can I reference downstream scopes?

Comment: Just create objects one by one.

Comment: You would have to explain why you need to do that to get an alternative solution. Those aren’t even “downstream scopes”; they’re just objects.

Comment: @minitech, I don't have an application. This is just an intellectual exercise.

Comment: Then the answer is that you can’t do that just from within `descend`. You could hack it together by using getters, but that’s not much more effective than keeping a reference to the object.

Comment: "intellectual exercise" --- it's an exercise for checking JS basics knowledge, far from something "intellectual"

Comment: @zerkms, I'm happy to call it a "dumb" exercise. Whatever floats your boat. :7)

Comment: Just doubt why this question is downvoted? I prefer this question over "help please fix my code" questions out there actually.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2980763/251311

Comment: Thanks, @zerkms! That answers my question. :7)