# Change property of 'parent' property

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am having troubles with objects properties for a NPM module.

I have this code:

```
var service = { //In my code this lane is: module.exports = { because is for a npm module so the client will call it using require();
    username: 'test',

    serviceFunction: function(){
        console.log(this.username); //Prints service.username
    },

    serviceObject: {                        
        getUsername: function () {
            console.log(this.username); //THIS IS CAUSING THE FAIL, ITS UNDEFINED
        }                   
    }                       
}
```

I can access `service.username` using `this.username` if it is located in a `serviceFunction`.

How can I do it while I am in `serviceObject.getUsername`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not retrieve information for a child object from within a parent object.

One option is to create an init function in the parent to set the same property in the child:-

```js
var service = { 
  username: 'test',

  serviceFunction: function() {
    console.log(this.username); 
  },

  serviceObject: {
    getUsername: function() {
      console.log(this.username); 
    }
  },
  init: function() {
    this.serviceObject.username = this.username;
  }
}

service.init()
service.serviceObject.getUsername(); // test
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Javascript expert but it seems like you have a object nested into another object. What you really try is to get a field of the parent, so "this" is definetly not binded to the object, you maybe think.

Take a look at this for good solutions: [Javascript objects: get parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980763/javascript-objects-get-parent)

Answer (score 1):

As @Enak said the `this` inside `getUsername` refers to `getUsername` instance.

If you `console.log(this)` inside `getUsername`, you will get `{ getUsername: [Function] }`

Instead of

`console.log(this.username);`

Use:

```
 serviceObject: {                        
        getUsername: function () {
            console.log(service.username); //'test'
        }                   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's `undefined` because the call-site of your `serviceObject.getUsername()` is explicitly bind to `serviceObject`, which does not have `username` property.

You may also use following syntax: `serviceObject.getUsername.call(service)` to bind `getUsername`'s `this` to `service`.

Remember, functions `this` binding is defined only by the call-site. Wherever you call `getUsername()`, `serviceObject.getUsername()`, `serviceObject.getUsername.call(service)`, you are basically binding to different objects.