# Can I navigate upwards through a javascript object in the same way I can through the DOM?

Tags: javascript, object, parent

I am computationally building a nested object in javascript (containing an arbitrary number of nested levels):

```
var myObject = {
                   iAmAKeyInALevel1Object: [

                       'iAmAnElementInALevel2Array',

                       {
                           iAmAKeyInALevel3Object: 'Level3'
                       }
                   ]
               }
```

I know I can access the value `'Level3'` with:

```
myObject.iamAKeyInALevel1Object[1].iAmAKeyInALevel3Object;
```

But if all I know is `'Level3'`, how can I access:

```
'Level3'.parentObject.parentArray.parentObject
```

or

```
'Level3'.parentObject.parentArray.parentObject.parentArray.parentObject
```

to return to a higher level `object`?

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2980763/5768908

Comment: It quite makes no sense to store a string and objects in an array, does it? And no it's not possible.

Comment: If you can, @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze, please can you expand on why it makes no sense? Thank you.

Comment: Normally you just save one kind of data into an array to keep "typesafety". E.g. integers, strings or objects. I know it's possible in javascript to not do so. It's more of a recommendation it does not mean you can't do it.