# Looping Through Nested JSON with Nested Child Searches

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON structure that looks like this:

```
"benefitValues" : [ {
          "changeDate" : "2017-10-13T20:26:13.000+0000",
          "changeUserName" : "aaaa",
          "numericValue" : 20,
          "value" : "20",
          "amountType" : {
            "allowCustomDataFlg" : false,
            "dataType" : "Percent",
            "defaultTypeFlg" : true,
            "defaultValue" : "Unlimited",
            "description" : null,
            "maxValue" : null,
            "minValue" : null,
            "name" : "LIST",
            "benefit" : {
              "category" : "Facility Services",
              "name" : "Single Limit",
              "networkStatus" : "IN_NETWORK",
              "planType" : "MedicalPlan",
              "sortOrder" : 20,
              "subcategory" : "Acupuncture Treatment",
              "subcategorySortOrder" : 6
            }
          }
        }]
```

Based on the string "Acupuncture Treatment", I need to extract the the value and the datatype.  The dataset is very large, with hundreds of subcategories.  I cannot find a good way to search through this data.  I tried json-path and advanced-json-path, but if I do a search on a child element, there is no way for me to return the parents.  I want my output to look like this:

```
{
          "Subcategory" : "Acupuncture Treatment",
          "Value" : "20",
          "Type" : "Percent"
}
```

I was hoping there was an easy way to do this with an existing library, or at least with a simple loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript objects: get parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980763/javascript-objects-get-parent)

Comment: You can't do it, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

This will find the matching element from`benefitValues`, and transform the element into the format you're expecting:

```js
var benefitValues = [{
  "changeDate": "2017-10-13T20:26:13.000+0000",
  "changeUserName": "aaaa",
  "numericValue": 20,
  "value": "20",
  "amountType": {
    "allowCustomDataFlg": false,
    "dataType": "Percent",
    "defaultTypeFlg": true,
    "defaultValue": "Unlimited",
    "description": null,
    "maxValue": null,
    "minValue": null,
    "name": "LIST",
    "benefit": {
      "category": "Facility Services",
      "name": "Single Limit",
      "networkStatus": "IN_NETWORK",
      "planType": "MedicalPlan",
      "sortOrder": 20,
      "subcategory": "Acupuncture Treatment",
      "subcategorySortOrder": 6
    }
  }
}];

// Find the element
let treatment = benefitValues.find((item) => item.amountType.benefit.subcategory === 'Acupuncture Treatment');

let result = {
  Value: treatment.value,
  Subcategory: treatment.amountType.benefit.subcategory,
  Type: treatment.amountType.dataType
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: this looks really good, but my actual live json call is returning the array within an empty container array like this 

[[{"changeDate": "2017-10-13T20:26:13.000+0000", etc, etc }]]

How do i get passed the empty container array?

Comment: i seemed to get rid of the outer array problem, but i am still getting this error Value: treatment.value, : TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Comment: Okay, that means that `find` isn&#39;t returning anything, so it&#39;s cant find one with that subcategory

Answer (score 0):

You can search through your data set and pull out only the items that match your string by using `.filter`. That would give you the entire object, so then you can use `.map` to transform it to the structure you want.

Or if you're only interested in the first result, you can use `.find` instead.

```js
const json = {"benefitValues" : [{
  "changeDate" : "2017-10-13T20:26:13.000+0000",
  "changeUserName" : "aaaa",
  "numericValue" : 20,
  "value" : "20",
  "amountType" : {
    "allowCustomDataFlg" : false,
    "dataType" : "Percent",
    "defaultTypeFlg" : true,
    "defaultValue" : "Unlimited",
    "description" : null,
    "maxValue" : null,
    "minValue" : null,
    "name" : "LIST",
    "benefit" : {
      "category" : "Facility Services",
      "name" : "Single Limit",
      "networkStatus" : "IN_NETWORK",
      "planType" : "MedicalPlan",
      "sortOrder" : 20,
      "subcategory" : "Acupuncture Treatment",
      "subcategorySortOrder" : 6
    }
  }
}]};

// With filter/map
const result = json.benefitValues
  .filter(val => val.amountType.benefit.subcategory === "Acupuncture Treatment")
  .map(val => ({Subcategory: val.amountType.benefit.subcategory, Value: val.value, Type: val.amountType.dataType}));
  
console.log(result)

// With find / manual transform:
const singleFullResult = json.benefitValues
  .find(val => val.amountType.benefit.subcategory === "Acupuncture Treatment")

const singleResult = {
  Subcategory: singleFullResult.amountType.benefit.subcategory,
  Value: singleFullResult.value,
  Type: singleFullResult.amountType.dataType
}

console.log(singleResult)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) combined with [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and create an array of object with the structure you need. Here's an example:

```js
let myArray = [{
    "changeDate": "2017-10-13T20:26:13.000+0000",
    "changeUserName": "aaaa",
    "numericValue": 20,
    "value": "20",
    "amountType": {
        "allowCustomDataFlg": false,
        "dataType": "Percent",
        "defaultTypeFlg": true,
        "defaultValue": "Unlimited",
        "description": null,
        "maxValue": null,
        "minValue": null,
        "name": "LIST",
        "benefit": {
            "category": "Facility Services",
            "name": "Single Limit",
            "networkStatus": "IN_NETWORK",
            "planType": "MedicalPlan",
            "sortOrder": 20,
            "subcategory": "Acupuncture Treatment",
            "subcategorySortOrder": 6
        }
    }
}];

let ret = myArray
                 .filter(arr => arr.amountType.benefit.subcategory === 'Acupuncture Treatment')
                 .map(arr => {
                         return {
                             Subcategory: arr.amountType.benefit.subcategory,
                             Value: arr.value,
                             Type: arr.amountType.dataType
                         };
                  });
console.log(ret);
```

First the filter function will filter your array and return only the items related to 'Acupuncture Treatment', then the map function, that receives as a parameter a function that will be executed for each item inside the array and it will return a new structure, will return only the fields you need.