# Name of object inside a each statment

Tags: javascript, jquery

Simple question...or so I think...

Is there a way to get the name of the object your looping through inside the each statement?

I need the name inside a loop so I can attach some elements to it on the page. This seems like the only way I can do so.

My full objects looks like this

```
 BO:{C: 1}
 CA1:{}
 CRA:{}
 DE:{RT: 14}
 TX:{}
```

These are smaller objects within a larger one that I am looping through.

and my for loop looks like this

```
$.each(v, function (o, p) {
  console.log(p)
  //looking the get the 'BO' or 'DE' inside here so I can do an append to the element on the page
});
```

When looping through this if I console out o, I get the variable C and when I console out the p I get the variable 1. As you can see below. I need to get the name of BO so need to go up and grab that variable so I can properly name my id.

I do not have access to outside variables within the for loop.

[image]

any help appreciated!

Comment: what is **v**? your *full object*?

Comment: that is an invalid object.

Comment: That is not an object...

Comment: use Object.keys(myObject)

Comment: Sorry, my entire object did not past correctly.  The v would be the BO:{C:1}

Comment: in that case if you want **BO**, you got it right there inside your loop, just `console.log(o)`

Comment: No, o comes back as C. I need to go up one level.

Comment: So you want to find a parent object name? despite having it there *BO* -
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980763/javascript-objects-get-parent

Comment: `!!CA1.BO` returns true. BO is right there inside the CA1 object.

Comment: Don't you have another $.each above that one? That $.each will have an argument that contains the value you are looking for.

Comment: @GeorgeCampbell, No BO is not returning. This is a loop within a loop so I can append html in different places. The loop above returns o which the value is C and p which the value is 1. I need to get the variable BO so I can label an id to append to. So I need to go up one level

Comment: It is still an invalid object. Please edit your question with valid code. Currently it is incomprehensible.

Comment: My goodness, can you post the entire context of your question? No body knows about that last statement.

Comment: @KevinB, I cannot seem to access any outside variables within this loop. Otherwise I would be happy to grab that

Comment: Prove it with a code sample.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterate through the properties of the object if you need just the name of the property, not its value :

```
var obj = {
  'BO': {
    'C': 1
  },
  'CA1': {},
  'CRA': {},
  'DE': {
    'RT': 14
  },
  'TX': {},
}

for( var s in obj ) {
  console.log(s);
}
```

Here's the working example : https://jsfiddle.net/yyLz0ae6/